# How to find the minimum and maximum value of a 10x12 matrix

Tags: c++

I have a program that calculate the amount of sales for a sales company using a 10x12 matrix.

The sales company has branches in 10 cities, and the program has to print the number of sales for each branch in the last 12 months. Then print the total number of the sales in the year, then the last thing is to print the minimum and maximum value of the sales

But the program does not print the correct minimum and maximum value

Here is the code

````
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double F[10][12];
    double sum[10] = { 0 };
    double Msum[12] = { 0 };

    int i = 0;
    int j;
    double x = 0;
    double max = 0;
    double Minimum = 100000000;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "please enter the " << i + 1 << " branch sale for the " << endl;
        for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            cout << "month " << j + 1 << ": " << endl;
            cin >> F[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            sum[i] += F[i][j];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "the total sales for branch " << i + 1 << " is " << sum[i] << endl;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            x += F[i][j];
        }
    cout << "the total sales for all branches in the year is " << x << endl;

    int min = INT_MAX;
    int max = INT_MIN; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 3 / 2; j++)
        {
            if (F[i][j] > F[i][3 - j - 1])
            {
                if (min > F[i][3 - j - 1])
                    min = F[i][3 - j - 1];
                if (max < F[i][j])
                    max = F[i][j];
            }
            else
            {
                if (min > F[i][j])
                    min = F[i][j];
                if (max < F[i][3 - j - 1])
                    max = F[i][3 - j - 1];
            }
        }
    }


    cout << "the branch that has the maximum sale in the year is " << max << endl;
    cout << "the month that has the least sales in the year is " << min << endl;
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: So what happened with the code when you tested it? I guess I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve. I have no idea what you are doing in the last part of the code starting with `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` that seems to have nothing to do with the stated problem of ***How to find the minimum and maximum value of a 10x12 matrix***

Comment: The reat of the code is working, but at the end the program has to print the minimum and maximum sale from all the branches in the last 12 months, but it's printing a wrong number